# How to detect if the player is using mouse and keyboard?(no controller connected)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to detect the device the player is using when playing the game. if it is (PS controller, X box Controller, or playing with mouse and keyboard(no controller is connected)...

```
void Start()
    {
        var gamepad = Gamepad.current;
        if (gamepad == null)
            return;
        if (gamepad is DualShockGamepad)
        {
          
            print("Playstation gamepad");

        }
        else if (gamepad is XInputController)
        {
                   
            print("Xbox gamepad");
        }
          
    }
```

I was able to detect the controllers, but how can I add a condition for the keyboard/mouse situation? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying below my code example

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class InputDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var gamepad = Gamepad.current;
        if (gamepad != null)
        {
            if (gamepad is DualShockGamepad)
            {
                print("PlayStation gamepad");
            }
            else if (gamepad is XInputController)
            {
                print("Xbox gamepad");
            }
        }
        else if (Keyboard.current != null || Mouse.current != null)
        {
            print("Mouse and keyboard");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Okashi please tick worked  for my answer bro

Comment: yes sorry I did

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You've posted 9 answers so far over the last 24 hours, and most of them are either mostly code with no explanation, appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), or both. A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. For answers where you have not used AI, keep in mind that providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* your code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.